# Checkbox não desseleciona no React Native

Tags: react-native, checkbox, react-hooks

Estou usando o *hook* `useState`, porém ele não altera o estado quando é pressionado novamente, ele fica marcado sempre.

```
const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState({});

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setSelection({
    ...isSelected,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.checked
  });
};

const checkboxes = [
  {
    name: 'check-box-1',
    key: 'checkBox1',
    label: 'Check Box 1'
  },
  {
    name: 'check-box-2',
    key: 'checkBox2',
    label: 'Check Box 2'
  }
];
```

---

```
<Container>
<StatusBar />

<View style={styles.container}>

{checkboxes.map(item => (
    <View style={styles.checkboxContainer} >
        <CheckBox
          name={item.name}
          checked={isSelected[item.name]}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label} > {item.name}</Text>
    </View>
))}

</View>
```

Comment: Esse `CheckBox`, é do React Native ou é componente de terceiros?

Comment: @react-native-community/checkbox

Comment: Ok. Entendi onde voce quer chegar, mas não entendi o porque voce fez dessa forma. Aceita outra forma de resolver isso como resposta?

Comment: sim sim, qualquer ajuda é muito bem vinda, a única restrição é que tenho que usar functions ao invés de classe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, os atributos `check` e `name` não existem na componente `CheckBox`, então não vamos usá-los. Vamos trabalhar apenas com os seguintes atributos:

- `value`, que irá armazenar um valor booleano (`true`/`false`);
- `onChange`, que irá ser o responsável por chamar uma função para tratar as mudanças no *checkbox*.

A lógica, que ao meu ver seria mais simples, é você trabalhar com o array `checkboxes` como um estado inicial do `useState`, e cada objeto que nele está contido, podemos acrescentar uma propriedade que chamaremos `checked`. Neste `checked` irá armazenar um valor booleano onde `true` é para quando o *checkbox* está selecionado, e `false` para quando não está.

Seria desta forma:

```
const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState([
  {
    name: 'check-box-1',
    key: 'checkBox1',
    label: 'Check Box 1',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'check-box-2',
    key: 'checkBox2',
    label: 'Check Box 2',
    checked: false
  }
]);
```

Os `check-box-n` inicialmente estarão desmarcados (`checked: false`). Agora vamos fazer um loop semelhante ao seu, só que agora vamos fazer o `map` em `isSelected` e não mais em `checkboxes`:

```
{isSelected.map((item, index) => (
  <View key={index}>
    <CheckBox
      value={item.checked}
      onChange={() => handleChange(item.name)}
    />
    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
  </View>
))}
```

<sub>Deixei os componentes acima sem os `styles`, pois eu montei o código apenas para elaborar a resposta. Faça os seus ajustes :)</sub>

Veja que eu usei o `index` apenas para passar para `key`.

Agora a lógica acima é bem simples. De acordo com o estado (`isSelected`), vamos renderizar um `CheckBox` de cada um dos itens que montarão esse *checkbox*.

Agora vamos falar da função `handleChange` em `onChange={() => handleChange(item.name)}`. Repare que passei para essa função, o nome do label que iremos alterar o estado quando selecionarmos o *checkbox*.

A função `handleChange`:

```
const handleChange = (name: string) => {
  const newState = isSelected.map(el => {
    const label = el;

    if (el.name === name) {
      label.checked = !el.checked;
    }

    return label;
  });

  setSelection(newState);
};
```

Vamos aos detalhes:

- `newState` irá receber um novo array baseado no estado inicial de `isSelected`. Usando o `map`, vamos retornar um array modificado e como será essa modificação? Veja a seguir...
- Dentro da função `handleChange`, `label` vai receber o estado inicial de cada elemento dentro do `isSelected`. Vamos verificar qual foi o label alterado graças ao nome que passamos para a função `handleChange`. Lembra?

```
//                             ↓↓↓↓ passamos aqui o nome do label que foi clicado                           
onChange={() => handleChange(item.name)}
```

Agora dentro do `if`, verificamos se o nome do label que foi alterado é o elemento atual do `map`. Se sim, vamos **inverter** o estado do `checked` usando o `!`:

```
if (el.name === name) {
  label.checked = !el.checked; // o que era "true" vira "false", e vice-versa
}
```

Por que inverter? Para quando clicarmos denovo no *checkbox*, ele deixa de ser `true` e passa a ser `false`, logo, o *checkbox* será desmarcado.

Depois de tudo, vamos alterar o estado antigo para o novo estado usando o `setSelection(newState)`.

```
const handleChange = (name) => {
  const newState = isSelected.map(el => {
    const label = el;

    if (el.name === name) { // verificamos se o nome do label foi passado na função
      label.checked = !el.checked; // se sim, vamos alterar o estado do "checked"
    }

    return label;
  });

  setSelection(newState); // atualiza o estado
};
```

Código final:

```
const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState([
  {
    name: 'check-box-1',
    key: 'checkBox1',
    label: 'Check Box 1',
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 'check-box-2',
    key: 'checkBox2',
    label: 'Check Box 2',
    checked: false
  }
]);

const handleChange = name => {
  const newState = isSelected.map(el => {
    const label = el;

    if (el.name === name) {
      // verificamos se o nome do label foi passado na função
      label.checked = !el.checked; // se sim, vamos alterar o estado do "checked"
    }

    return label;
  });

  setSelection(newState); // atualiza o estado
};
```

```
<View>
  {isSelected.map((item, index) => (
    <View key={index}>
      <CheckBox
        value={item.checked}
        onChange={() => handleChange(item.name)}
      />
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  ))}
</View>
```

Comment: amigo(a) MUITO OBRIGADO, você salvo uma issue minha kkk, eu tava complicando muito... entendi tudo, agradeço demais a ajuda que você me deu, espero que um dia eu consiga retribuir, muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: mas qual a diferença entre colocar a key={index} dentro da view e dentro do componente checkbox?

Comment: as chaves (key) usadas nos arrays devem ser únicas entre seus elementos irmãos, no caso as `View`, por isso a key deve ficar na `View`. Você está renderizando várias `View`s dentro do `map`.

Comment: ok muito obrigado pela explicação ! obrigado pela ajuda!